# Is there a way to replace an object with another one AND its children?

Tags: parent, linked-data, groups

I want to replace several objects with a group of objects each. So I tried it with a parent group and linked the data oft the parent with the objects I want to replace, but it only links the data of the parent. Has anybody an idea how to replace an object with a group of objects?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with geometry nodes.

- Add your object(s) you want to duplicate/instance in a new collection. Position the object(s) origin on world origin. This can be any number of objects/meshes.

[image]

- Select an object you want to be replaced and add the Geometry Nodes modifier. In my case, I'm going to replace four cubes. Make sure that these objects are not in the same collection of the objects you want to duplicate.

[image]

- In the Geometry Node Editor, create a Collection Info node and join the Geometry output of the node to the Geometry input of the Group Output node. In the Collection Info node, select the collection of the object(s) you want to duplicate. If you want to apply the Geometry Node modifier to get a real mesh, add a Realize Instances node between the Collection Info and Group Output node.

[image]

- The cube with the modifier attached should be replaced with the new mesh. Last step is to select all the objects to replace, then select the object with the modifier on it (should be highlighted light orange), and press Ctrl+L and Copy Modifiers.

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. The Problem whit this is, that this only works with mesh Objects an one of my children objects is a lamp. Sorry i forgot to mention this maybe... But especially its one mesh after i apply the node modifier and not still a Parent group...

Comment: Maybe you got also an idea for that?

Comment: If you remove the Realize Instance node. Lights and other non mesh objects are copied aswell. You can't edit the new instances separately though because they copy the original. If you need to edit the new instances, you can select it, ctrl+A > Make Instances Real. This wont preserve parenting however.

Comment: Ok, not perfect, but pretty damn close! :D Thank you very much, that helps me a lot!

Comment: @Benus It does, if you enable Parent in the Make Instances Real operator