# How can I replace all of these scattered Objects with a new Group Object?

Tags: modeling, objects, linked-data, object-mode

I know this is possible but I am stumped. I know how to replace a selection with the data mesh of another, but what if there is more than one data mesh?

[I built this project as a case study.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6yzrbmh3nl4vrc0/Replace%20Objects%20How.blend?dl=0)

I have a pile of cubes that I want to replace (each cube gets replaced) with a new object, which is three objects joined together with a parent.

How would I go about doing this?

[image]

Comment: I guess you need to join the 3 objects then select all the cubes, shift select the object, and Ctrl L > Link Object Data

Comment: Thanks @moonboots.  I actually found another post that has a solution that uses Geometry Nodes.

Comment: This is the solution I found: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/249344/is-there-a-way-to-replace-an-object-with-another-one-and-its-children